# LINQ To SQL with type-safe integer class

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have the following class designed to provide a type-safe mechanism to pass an `Int64` into my business layer:

```
class ClientID {
    public ClientID(long i) { Value = i; }
    //... other constructors

    public long Value { get; private set; }

    public static bool operator ==(ClientID lhs, long rhs) {
        return lhs.Value == rhs;
    }
}
```

There are a few other comparison operators, plus some `Object` overrides. This allows me to write LINQ code that says:

```
ClientID searchID = something;

from i in someSQLdatasource
where i.ClientID == searchID
select i;
```

The syntax works, but of course LINQ to SQL cannot generate the SQL code for my `ClientID` class. I could explicitly reference the `Value` property, but I think the syntax I used is more elegant.

Can anyone help me in coercing LINQ to SQL to generate a comparison just as if my `ClientID` class were an `Int64`?

Comment: Did you try defining an implicit conversion operator from `ClientID` to `Int64`?

Comment: I did: public static implicit operator Int64(ClientID c) { return c.Value; } Same problem.

Comment: What is it you think you are getting by not just declaring Int64 as the property type instead of your class?

Comment: Oh, very much. I use bigint as my primary key in many tables. When I want to look them up, I pass them from the presentation layer to my middle tier. Because my company has multiple customers all in the same database, nearly every middle tier call includes the Int64 that represents the customer. All this means that a large percentage of my middle tier lookup methods have 2 or more Int64 parameters, and keeping them straight is difficult. By wrapping some or all of them in these shells, the compiler forces me to get the order right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, in the version of LinqToSQL in ASP.NET 4.0, this is no longer needed, and my class translates to SQL just fine. That is, the following class:

```
public class ObjectID {
    public Int64 Value { get { return m_Value; } set { m_Value = value; } }

    protected ObjectID(Int64 v) { Value = v; }
    protected ObjectID(String v) { Value = Int64.Parse(v); }
    protected ObjectID(System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField v) { Value = v.Value == "" ? 0 : Int64.Parse(v.Value); }
    protected ObjectID(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs v) { Value = Int64.Parse(v.CommandArgument.ToString()); }
    protected ObjectID(object v) { Value = Int64.Parse(v.ToString()); }

    public static bool operator ==(ObjectID lhs, ObjectID rhs) { return lhs.Value == rhs.Value; }
    public static bool operator !=(ObjectID lhs, ObjectID rhs) { return lhs.Value != rhs.Value; }

    public static implicit operator Int64(ObjectID c) { return c.Value; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj.GetType() == this.GetType()) return (ObjectID)obj == this;
        if (obj is Int64) return this.Value == (Int64)obj;
        return false;
    } // Equals

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    } // GetHashCode

    public override string ToString() {
        return Value.ToString();
    } // ToString

    private Int64 m_Value;
} // class ObjectID
```

Allows me to write 
    Where(f => f.InvoiceID == ID)

and have LinqToSQL make the necessary translation. I can then build classes that are derived from ObjectID, and get my type-safe containers that work right within SQL.

Comment: Hard to believe. You didn't change anything?

Comment: Actually, I was able to take code out. The class above works perfectly.

Comment: Can you capture the SQL executed using SQL Server Profiler? My guess is that the where is executing client-side. L2S sometimes does this silently. Edit: If it does, your performance will be destroyed.

Comment: Good suggestion. I did so, and the generated SQL includes the ID column in the WHERE clause. So, in fact, somewhere in the revision, L2S began figuring out how to crawl through the expression trees just a little smarter.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL doesn't have any way of coercing it to do things. The best you can hope for is rewriting the Expression tree before it gets it which is non-trivial.  http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider is a simple example of how to intercept the tree and modify what providers see.

Comment: That you for the reference. I looked all over the internet, somehow never came across your blog. I'm pretty sure this is what I want, will get a chance to place with it come Monday.

Comment: Thanks. I have asked a followup on your blog to try and get this working for me.